# Do not allow StatusBar to position itself

Tags: c, winapi

When I create a StatusBar, `CreateWindowEx()` will ignore the X and Y coordinates that I specify and the StatusBar will be positioned at the bottom of the parent Window.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

---

**Edit:**

This is the code to create the StatusBar:

```
CreateWindowEx(0, STATUSCLASSNAME, "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 0, 0, hParentWindow, 0, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

As you can see, the X and Y coordinates are (0,0), but the StatusBar will be placed at the bottom of the parent Window.

Comment: Could you provide the full code that you are using to do this?

Comment: Well, not the *full* code, but the minimum amount of code required to show the problem occurring and still be compilable.

Comment: In a word, no. The status bar is a special window, just like the application menu is - it's managed (sized and positioned) by windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The status bar is hard-coded to appear at the bottom of its parent window, and this can't be changed. However what you can change is the parent window.

So to position the status bar in an arbitrary location, put it inside a child window. You can then position the child window as you want.

Just remember that any notifications from the status bar will now go to the child window.